# Edge ломает всё. Видео по всему блоку

Tags: html, css

[image: Так выглядит в Edge]

Как сделать чтобы видео было по всему кругу, а не только по центру?
Не могу растянуть видео....

```css
body {
    padding: 16px;
}

video {
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 34vw;
    height: 33vw;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 17px #adddf3;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 17px #adddf3;
    padding-bottom: 0vw;
    padding-top: 0vw;
    padding-left: 0vw;
    padding-right: 0vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://i.imgur.com/6ucWers.mp4" autoplay loop />
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать круглое видео?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/897314/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be)