# Как сделать круглое видео?

Tags: html, css, html5, видео

Не могу сделать круглое видео. В сhrome все роботает, а в Edge не знаю как сделать

Как сделать чтобы видео было по всему кругу, а не только по центру?
Не могу растянуть видео....

```css
body {
    padding: 16px;
}

video {
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 34vw;
    height: 33vw;
    border-radius: 100% 100% 100% 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 17px #adddf3;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 17px #adddf3;
    padding-bottom: 0vw;
    padding-top: 0vw;
    padding-left: 0vw;
    padding-right: 0vw;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<video src="https://i.imgur.com/6ucWers.mp4" autoplay loop />
```

[image: скриншот]

Результат в IE:

[image: Результат в IE]

Comment: Выложите ваш код в сниппет чтоб удалось воспроизвести что не работает или не так работает и тогда вам помогут.

Comment: Edge не поддерживает object-fit для видео. Оборачивайте видео в див, и все стили кружочка присваивайте уже диву

Comment: Пока поддержка [только картинок](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/objectfitandobjectpositionvideocanvasetc/)

Comment: [вот тут вроде как обход есть](https://medium.com/@primozcigler/neat-trick-for-css-object-fit-fallback-on-edge-and-other-browsers-afbc53bbb2c3)

Comment: Пожалуйста, не надо задавать однотипные вопросы.

Comment: голосуйте за закрытие (как дубликата) не этого вопроса, а того, что озаглавлен «edge ломате всё…»

Comment: А галочка будет?

Answer (score 3):

```css
video {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: что-то приплюснутое какое-то :)

Comment: @Grundy, чтобы было совсем круглое, надо взять квадратное видео, а у меня нет :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, на самом деле вся соль в квадратной обёртке - видео может быть любой формы и любого размера.

Comment: @Grundy, запостил ещё ответ для квадраторезки.

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно обрезать горизонтальное видео под круг на основе его высоты, то можно сделать так:

```css
section {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 85vmin;
  position: relative;
}

section::before {
  content: "";
  padding-top: 100%;
  display: block;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Задаёте блоку `.videocontainer` какие-то квадратные размеры (типа там `400` на `400`), `border-radius: 50%` и - обязательно - `overflow: hidden`.

А видео задаёте `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 1):

Для тега `<video>` можно использовать свойство [`object-fit: cover;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

```css
section {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 10px #adddf3;
  margin: 13px;
}

section > video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <video autoplay loop muted>
    <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="//www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</section>
```